# Springboot backend wont connect with Axios call from Vue

Tags: spring, vue.js, spring-security

I'm trying to configure a login using Vue on the front and Springboot on the backend. But I can't seem to get them to talk to each other. My Vue is running on port 3000 and my Tomcat is on port 8080

My Security -

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/sign-in")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/dashboard", true)
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout().deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
            .and()
            .rememberMe().key("uniqueAndSecret");
            http.cors();
}
```

My controller -

```
@Controller
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/v1/auth",
                produces = "application/json",
                method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.PUT})
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/sign-in")
    public String login() {
        return "sign-in";
    }
}
```

My Axios Post call from "SignIn.vue" -

```
  submit() {
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.set("email", this.email);
    formData.set("password", this.password);

    // post api url will be - /api/v1/auth/sign-in after backend and frontend are running on the same port

    axios.post('http://localhost:8080/sign-in', formData,
        {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}})
    .then(function(res) {
      if(res.data.code === 200) {
        this.router.push('/dashboard')
      }
      else {
        this.msg = response.message;
      }
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      this.msg = 'error';
    })
  }
```

Comment: What error is coming, have you checked it may be failing because of cors.

Comment: @NirajJha I fixed the previous CORS issue I had already. This is what I'm getting in the console - GET http://localhost:8080/login 404

Comment: Have you set up the view resolver for /login, this is not a service it should map with a view otherwise 404 will give you.

Comment: @NirajJha I don't believe so. How do you do that?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your LoginController class level RequestMapping '/api/v1/auth' combined with your 'login()' method level RequestMapping '/sign-in', you should be sending your login request to the URL 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/auth/sign-in'.

Comment: That's exactly how I originally configured it, but I kept getting "GET http://localhost:8080/login 404" for some reason

Comment: If you haven't already, I recommend testing your REST endpoint with an program like Postman or Insomnia.  I have built both Vue.js clients and Spring REST APIs, so I would test the backend until I have the request format correct, and then make sure that my Vue app is sending that request.

Comment: Just tested that full path for the API on postman and I'm getting  a 404 error.



{
    "timestamp": "2021-03-10T23:29:01.162+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "",
    "path": "/login"
}

Comment: It's still pointing towards login. I think that's where my problem is, but I can't seem to null out how to point it to my SignIn.vue page. That comes up no problem in the browser, so I know that vue itself is working

Comment: Possibly it is a security config error where Spring is trying to redirect you to '/login'.  Try disabling Spring Security temporarily to see if you can get your API to respond.

Comment: That is what I'm thinking as well, but without it, it is throwing me a 401 error in Postman

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it is a Spring Security error.  I have used it a few times, so am not an  expert.  At this point, you may just need to read up on and mess with SS until you get it working.  Or post a different question focused on SS configuration.

Comment: That's the plan. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score -1):

Please see how to handle the view or custom login.
[page](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.20.RELEASE/guides/html5/form-javaconfig.html)

You can find similar documentation in the latest release also.